# Excel bug or feature: "IF" isn't case sensitive?

Tags: excel

Even realized: `=IF(A2=B2,"equals","not equals")` makes no difference between higher an lower cases.

It delivers `equals` on comparing of `example.com/Lesezeichen.html` and `example.com/lesezeichen.html`.

Or is it an issue of german Excel?

Comment: No, this happens in English too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is an `Exact` function which looks for the *exact* text including case sensitivity

`=IF(exact(A2,B2),"equals","not equals")`

Comment: means, `=` is good only for numeric values. Every day something new:) Thank you!

Comment: Yup learning something new. I didn't realize it because I don't really work with text too often (or as precisely), but learned about the `Exact` function for this, so we both learned a little bit!